# What is the __STDC_VERSION__ value for C11?

Tags: c, macros, iso, c11

I know that compilers use `__STDC__` to indicate that a compiler is standard C and, from, there, you can use `__STDC_VERSION__` to figure out which *level* of the standard you're using.

I also know that C90 had no value, C90 amendment 1 had `199401L` and C99 had `199901L`.

The latest C1x draft I have simply states it as `201ymmL` and I'm assuming it was made a less "vague" value in the final standard.

My guess is that it will be `201112L` since that's when C11 was ratified but I'd like to be certain.

I thought I could try using `gcc -std=c1x` but the version of `gcc` I'm running doesn't support that yet.

Does anyone know what the actual value is?

Comment: In any case the numbering of C versions is sufficiently coarse such that you can just test for `> 201100L`.

Comment: Duplicate: [What is C11 cor 1:2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914050/what-is-c11-cor-12012).

Comment: Lundin: have closed the dupe.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah well... neither you nor me were suitable for doing that (closing a post as a dupe with our own post as target), since we are partial. The linked one isn't a dupe of this though, but the other way around, since the TC contained other things than `__STDC_VERSION__` as well.

Comment: As an addendum for anyone looking, the value for C17 is `201710L`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With `-std=c11` in `gcc`, `201112L` is used for `__STDC_VERSION__`

See this `gcc` patch on December 20, 2011 on `gcc` ml:

https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg23572.html

And note that apparently the ISO version of C11 forgot to update the `201ymmL` from the Draft.

> The intended final `__STDC_VERSION__` value, `201112L`, is also implemented (the editor forgot to update the `201ymmL` placeholders before sending the document for publication by ISO).

See also [DR #411](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_411.htm), which makes it official that the intended value is `201112l`.  The editor has said that ["The committee is trying to get it approved as a TC as soon as possible."](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/msg/fa7c42c23e327580).  (TC = "Technical Corrigendum")

**EDIT (July 16, 2012):** Technical Corrigendum 1 ([ISO/IEC 9899:2011/Cor 1:2012](https://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=61717)) released on July 15, 2012 fixes the `__STDC_VERSION__` to `201112L`.

Comment: Which version of gcc is that? My Ubuntu 1104 one is 4.5.2 and I'll be stuffed if I'm upgrading to 1110, given the fact I've heard that hideous Unity interface is no longer optional :-)

Comment: it seems that `-std=c11` has been added to `gcc` 4.7 http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html

Comment: @paxdiablo: you can get rid of Unity, but since the patch was submitted Dec 20, it wasn't in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll wait for 1204 and hope that Shuttleworth et al come to their senses :-)

Comment: I have the final ISO version and I can confirm that they have forgotten to change it. It still says "201ymmL" just as in the draft.

Comment: ISO released a corrigendum yesterday 2012-07-15 *Cor 1:2012* for C11: value `__STDC_VERSION__` is now fixed to `201112L` http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=61717

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.patches/254497) post to the GCC mailing list, the final value is, as you suspected, `201112L`.