# How do I check by using __STDC_VERSION__ if is -std=c1x in use?

Tags: c, gcc4, c11

I know that for C11, I can test `#if(__STDC_VERSION >= 20112L)`. But for `-std=c1x`

what macro and/or value should I test it?

what's the nomenclature of this standard? or maybe a informal name, if any.
I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gcc's `-std=c1x` option is synonymous with `-std=c11`, and it sets `__STDC_VERSION__` to the same value, `201112L` (note: *not* `20112L`).

Before it was released, the new C standard was referred to as "C1X" (since it wasn't known exactly when it would come out), and gcc added a `-std=c1x` option to enable *partial* support for the upcoming standard. When the standard was released as C11, gcc added `-std=c11` to enable (still partial) support, but has kept the `-std=c1x` option for compatibility.

(Due to an editing error, the released 2011 ISO C standard doesn't specify the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`, but the editor has stated that `201112L` is correct; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9294207/827263).)

Jens Gustedt's comment makes a good point. `gcc -std=c11` sets `__STDC_VERSION__` to `201112LL`, which is supposed to imply C11 conformance, but in fact it's still missing a log of C11 features. We can expect this to improve in future releases.

Similarly, `-std=c99` sets `__STDC_VERSION__` to `199901L`, but it doesn't *quite* conform to the C99 standard (the current status is documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html).  gcc's C90 conformance (with `-ansi` or `-std=c90`) conforms quite well to the C90 standard.

Comment: +1, but I think one should really emphasize on the fact that this is not a feature test macro, since `-std=c11` sets this without implementing all mandatory featurers of C11. Basically, to my experience, you can't deduce much from the value of `__STDC_VERSION__` for your code.