# How can I find number of times a recursive function calls itself?

Tags: c, recursion

Consider the following recursive C function.

```
 void get (int n) { 
    if (n<1) return; 
    get (n-1) ; 
    get (n-3) ; 
    printf ("%d", n) ; 
    }
```

If `get(6)` function is being called in `main()` then how many times will the `get()` function be invoked before returning to the main `0` ?

Comment: That will depend on the value of the (global?) variable `l`, I think...

Comment: I recommend putting in a counter (a static variable) that increments every time `get()` is entered.

Comment: @glglgl: I'm guessing that's a typo -- `l` should be `1` (ell should be one)

Comment: @Gabe I would have up-voted it if it was a answer.. Very good suggestion

Comment: I would imagine that `l` (`L`) is a typo and the author meant to write `1` (one).

Comment: @Gabe, ahh, you beat me to pointing that out.

Comment: Why don't you just run it and find out?

Comment: I'm not sure what anyone else thinks, but this kind of sounds like a homework question.

Comment: just put some static variable or global variable increment it in get function and print. for get(6) if l=1 then 25.

Comment: that is indeed an exam Question :)

Comment: Exam in the class: irrelevant C knowledge. A good c programming class would rather reach you to avoid recursion whenever possible. This is kind of like a driving class teaching you the best ways to crash your car or how to drive really slow on the free-way. "It is good to know". No, not really. Why would you want to drive slow with the risk of crashing, when you could drive bother faster and safer?

Comment: @Lundin Well it's basically to test knowledge of students "if they understand recursion or not", Its like testing them for basics so that higher things could be taught to them.

Comment: @RishiPrakash No it's all about teaching them bad practice, so that they end up using it in real-world applications later on, turning the applications into slow, buggy crap. The uses for recursion are so very limited that the average professional programmer never encounters a valid use-case for it.  The only valid, but extremely narrow case I know of myself, is when you are picky about optimizing a BST for storage size, by implementing the BST with nodes that don't have a parent pointer. Yet plenty of programming classes forces beginners to study recursion, which is outright harmful.

Comment: @Lundin experience speaks, I agree because whatever you would be saying must be saying with all the experience and time you have spent with real world programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To figure out how many times your function gets called, increment a static counter every time the function is entered and the print out the value after the call. For instance:

```
int counter;
void get (int n) { 
    ++counter; /* increment counter before first return */
    if (n<1) return; 
    get (n-1) ; 
    get (n-3) ; 
    printf ("%d", n) ; 
}

int main()
{
    counter = 0; /* reset counter before each use */
    get(6);
    printf("get() was called %d times\n", counter);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, There's no need to initialize `counter` in `main()`. Global variable in C [are guaranteed to be initialized to zero](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16015656/119527).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You are absolutely right, but I wanted to make the code so it could be reused; that is, you could call it in a loop or copy/paste it to see how many times the function gets called with different input parameters.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Writing code that relies on implicit zero-initialization of objects with static storage duration is very bad practice. Dangerous, unmaintainable, confusing.

Comment: @Lund in Citation, please? I don't see how it's any different than not `memset`-ing a buffer returned by `calloc` to all-zeroes.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I can't cite common sense. Suppose for example that you have a global variable and someone maintaining the code finds this ugly and unnecessary, so they move it to local scope, which is a reasonable thing to do. This maintenance exposed a bug written by the original programmer. Which could have easily been avoided by writing `int counter=0;`.

Comment: I'm afraid we'll have to agree to disagree that this is a "bug" by the original author. There are multiple problems with your scenario: 1) He can't move this variable to a local scope because it's referenced by another function. When he goes to compile, he's reminded that it is a global, and because he knows the language, he knows that it was zero-initialized. 2) Because he's a good programmer, he has compiler warnings enabled and sees that his now-local variable is uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

Considering this is certainly an academic exercise, it may behoove you to understand how the recursion is working.

We can modify your code to print out a call tree, showing each invocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get(int n, int depth)
{ 
    static int call = 1;
    printf("%3d: %*sget(%d)\n", call++, 2*depth, "", n); 
    if (n<1)
        return; 
    get(n-1, depth+1); 
    get(n-3, depth+1); 
}

int main(void)
{
    get(6, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
  1: get(6)
  2:   get(5)
  3:     get(4)
  4:       get(3)
  5:         get(2)
  6:           get(1)
  7:             get(0)
  8:             get(-2)
  9:           get(-1)
 10:         get(0)
 11:       get(1)
 12:         get(0)
 13:         get(-2)
 14:     get(2)
 15:       get(1)
 16:         get(0)
 17:         get(-2)
 18:       get(-1)
 19:   get(3)
 20:     get(2)
 21:       get(1)
 22:         get(0)
 23:         get(-2)
 24:       get(-1)
 25:     get(0)
```

Note that I am assuming your assignment states `if (n<1)` ("one"), not `if (n<l)` ("ell").  Also, notice that I added a `depth` parameter. This allowed me to indent each call appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

We can make a recurrence relation for above function as:

```
T(n) = T(n-1)  +  T(n-3) + 2

T(n)=1 for n<=0
```

I've added `2` in the equation since we are calling the recursive function twice.

Start by by substituting from `n=1` at `n=6` you will get ans as `25`