# why am i getting segmentation fault with strcpy()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
```

trying to put fields into my struct but getting segmentation fault when i strcpy them in

```
typedef struct country {
    char code_name[3];
    char name[44];
    int population;
    float life_expect;
}country[244];

country *data;

int main(void) {


    char c;
    char *ptr;
    int i;
    int temp;
    char buf[512];
    char *token;

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("AllCountries.dat", "r");
```

in here where i call `strcpy(data[i]->code_name, token)` i get a segmentation fualt. why is that? what am i doing wrong?

```
    do {
        if (fgets(buf, 512 , fptr)){
            //printf("%s\n",buf);
            token = strtok(buf,",");
            while (token != NULL){          
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                if (temp == 0){
                strcpy(data[i]->code_name, token);
                printf("%s, ",token);
                } temp = temp + 1;
            //printf("%s, ",token); 
            //printf("code_name: %s\n", data->code_name);                   
            }
        i++;
        temp = 0;
        }

    }while ((feof(fptr))  != EOF);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

the file

```
115,DZA,Algeria,Africa,Northern Africa,2381741,1962,31471000,69.7,49982,Al-Jazair/Algérie,Republic,Abdelaziz Bouteflika,35,DZ
146,AGO,Angola,Africa,Central Africa,1246700,1975,12878000,38.3,6648,Angola,Republic,José Eduardo dos Santos,56,AO
94,BEN,Benin,Africa,Western Africa,112622,1960,6097000,50.2,2357,Bénin,Republic,Mathieu Kérékou,187,BJ
129,BWA,Botswana,Africa,Southern Africa,581730,1966,1622000,39.3,4834,Botswana,Republic,Festus G. Mogae,204,BW
193,IOT,British Indian Ocean Territory,Africa,Eastern Africa,78,NULL,0,NULL,0,British Indian Ocean Territory,Dependent Territory of the UK,Elisabeth II,NULL,IO
95,BFA,Burkina Faso,Africa,Western Africa,274000,1960,11937000,46.7,2425,Burkina Faso,Republic,Blaise Compaoré,549,BF
```

Comment: Where did you allocate memory for `data`?

Comment: doesnt it take the allocation for country? or am i wrong

Comment: There is no allocation for `country`. It's a type definition, not a variable.

Comment: `data` here is a pointer to a block of memory. But that block of memory doesn't exist.

Comment: Show example of `AllCountries.dat`.

Comment: ok then how would i put the token into my struct for code_name?

Comment: Please format your code properly. The `indent` program can do this automatically for you.

Comment: Other issues: `i` is never initialized. It might be 0. It might be 20380923. How you're reading the file is unnecessarily complicated. `fgets` returns NULL if it can't read for whatever reason, so `while( fgets(...) != NULL ) { ... }` is enough.

Comment: ah, the ol' while-if loop.

Comment: `char code_name[3];` --> `char code_name[4];` Size including NUL characters is required. `token = strtok(NULL, ",");` : `token` needs check not `NULL`.

Comment: `int temp;` also uninitialize --> `int temp = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a pointer variable `data`, but never assigned it to point to any memory. You need to do this in `main()`:

```
data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
```

But there's no real need for a pointer here, just declare an ordinary variable:

```
country data;
```

Actually, I suggest that you don't put the array dimension in the type definition. You should declare the structure type, then declare an array of structures.

```
typedef struct country {
    char code_name[3];
    char name[44];
    int population;
    float life_expect;
} country;

country data[244];
```

If you still wanted to use a pointer instead of a regular variable, it would be:

```
country *data;
```

then in `main()` you would do:

```
data = malloc(244 * sizeof(*data));
```

You also need to initialize `i`:

```
int i = 0;
```

and

```
}while ((feof(fptr))  != EOF);
```

is wrong. `feof()` returns `1` when EOF is reached, not `EOF`. It should be:

```
} while (!feof(fptr));
```

Comment: thank you! this worked didn't realize what i was doing wrong

Comment: @jhowe You're copying every field of the file into the `code_name` field, but since it's declared `char[3]`, it can only hold 2 characters (the third byte is for the null terminator). So you're writing outside the bounds of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: quick question how do i pass an integer from the file to population in the struct i tried this:    data[i].population = atoi(token);
    strcpy(data[i].population, token);                                  but it didnt work

Comment: `data[i].population = atoi(token)` should work. You don't need to use `strcpy()` for `population` since it's not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because the destination, `data`, which is a pointer to typedef'ed `country`, is NULL.

`strcpy()` access the given `NULL`, and segfaults.

The variable `data` is a global variable and initialized to NULL in C.

ref: [Why are global and static variables initialized to their default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091499), [Are global variables always initalized to zero in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16015656)