# Is Aggregate Initialization of Bit-Fields Allowed?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, bit-fields, aggregate-initialization

I have a struct which contains bit-fields:

```
struct Foo {
    unsigned a : 16, b : 16;
};
```

And I want to know if I can use aggregate initialization on it's bit-fields. For example:

```
struct Foo bar = {13, 42};
```

I note that this [does work in gcc 5.1](http://ideone.com/ruSyn9) and Visual Studio 2015. I'd just like something to certify this was standard approved initialization for both C and C++.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: @Olaf I have a library that is used by both C and C++. So I can't pick one, and I'd certainly like if the answer was the same for both. Incidentally, gcc works fine for both, here's the C counterpart to my example in the question: http://ideone.com/a3iVXw

Comment: @JonathanMee: "I have a library" - Use the language the library is compiled as. Semantics for C and C++ are sometimes subtle different. See one of my comments above. There is actually little use for bitfields in C. If you have to (un)pack fields in an integral type, just use bitops; a good compiler will generate much the same code, but you get a specific layout. And using bitfields with a type of implementation-dependent size is always a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf I'm saying that the code I'm writing will be used as a library in two separate projects. One is C++ and one is C. If I need to put `#ifdef`s in I can, but it sounds like that is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Writing a library in the quite small common subset of C and C++ sounds like a bad approach. Anyway: your project, your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From C++14 `[dcl.init.aggr]` we have

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

So `Foo` is an aggregate an qualifies for aggregate initialization.  Then we have

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order.[...]

and

> Static data members and anonymous bit-fields are not considered members of the class for purposes of aggregate initialization.

So in your case they will be initialized since they are not anonymous and they will be initialized in the order they appear in the `struct`.

From C11 6.2.5(21) we have

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.<sup>46</sup>)

So in C we are still dealing with an aggregate.  Then in 6.7.9(9) we have

> Except where explicitly stated otherwise, for the purposes of this subclause unnamed members of objects of structure and union type do not participate in initialization. Unnamed members of structure objects have indeterminate value even after initialization.

and 6.7.9(17)

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.<sup>148</sup>) In contrast, a designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator.<sup>149</sup>)

So we have the same behavior as in C++ where anonymous bit fields are not initialized but since they are named they will be initialized in the order they appear in the `struct`.

Comment: The answer is incomplete. The question is tahhed C and C++.

Comment: @Olaf I have updated the answer with the C part.  I was working on gathering the relevant standardies and My C standard pdf is a littler harder to search than my C++ one.

Comment: It is always better to provide links to the standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html .

Comment: @Olaf If you want to be picky, then there is no way to provide links to the standards, since they are not publicly available. (However, at least C11 is almost identical to the draft. The only difference I have found is that the official standard comes with [Cor 1:2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914050/what-is-c11-cor-12012).)

Comment: @Lundin: While technically you are correct, as you mentioned there is no significant difference between the draft and the actual standard. In fact, the cnages were to expect; I just wonder why they appear in a corrigendum and not the final standard itself. Anyway, that link was mostly to provide an easier to search and link version, as NathanOliver mentions he just has a pdf. It is quite a shame a standard which was paid by public money (at least the German DIN is) still costs (quite a lot of) money.