# How does the below program output `C89` when compiled in C89 mode and `C99` when compiled in C99 mode?

Tags: c, printf, comments, c99, c89

I've found this C program from the web:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("C%d\n",(int)(90-(-4.5//**/
    -4.5)));

    return 0;
}
```

The interesting thing with this program is that when it is compiled and run in C89 mode, it prints `C89` and when it is compiled and run in C99 mode, it prints `C99`. But I am not able to figure out how this program works.

Can you explain how the second argument of `printf` works in the above program?

Comment: Hint: the C++-style `//` comment was introduced in C99.

Comment: Nice trick – but it fails with `gcc`. Without `std=c99` you'll get a warning, and if you ignore it, `gcc` will *still* interpret the `//` as start of a comment (ah – you have to use `-pedantic` as well. I have that on by default.)

Comment: @Jongware Well, I got `C89` with explicit `std=c89` in gcc 4.9.2.

Comment: Just in case someone finds this while searching for a way to test for C99 support; please use something like `#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L`, not the `//` comment trick. =)

Comment: It also prints "C99" for C11...

Comment: @Arkku Never knew that before. Thanks!

Comment: @CoolGuy Correct way to obtain C version posted below.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah saw it. I also googled `__STDC_VERSION__` and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9294314/3049655) and [this](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/STDC_VERSION) very helpful

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038200/write-a-program-that-will-print-c-if-compiled-as-an-ansi-c-program-and-c

Comment: Is `printf()` integer argument  cast  redundant `(int)` ?

Comment: @EsmaeelE No, it is required as the result of the operation is a `double` but the `%d` format specifier expects an `int`.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

C99 allows `//`-style comments, C89 does not. So, to translate:

C99:

```
 printf("C%d\n",(int)(90-(-4.5     /*Some  comment stuff*/
                         -4.5)));
// Outputs: 99
```

C89:

```
printf("C%d\n",(int)(90-(-4.5/      
                         -4.5)));
/* so  we get 90-1 or 89 */
```

Answer (score 25):

the line comment `//` is introduced since C99. Therefore your code is equal to this in C89

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("C%d\n",(int)(90-(-4.5/
-4.5)));

    return 0;
}
/* 90 - (-4.5 / -4.5) = 89 */
```

and equal to this in C99

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("C%d\n",(int)(90-(-4.5
-4.5)));

    return 0;
}
/* 90 - (-4.5 - 4.5) = 99*/
```

Answer (score 9):

Because `//` comments only exist in C99 and later standards, the code is equivalent to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int vers;

  #if   __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
    vers = 99; // oops
  #elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    vers = 99;
  #else
    vers = 90;
  #endif

  printf("C%d", vers);

  return 0;
}
```

Correct code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int vers;

  #if   __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
    vers = 11;
  #elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    vers = 99;
  #else
    vers = 90;
  #endif

  printf("C%d", vers);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: off-by-one error in your answer, how do you get 90 when it's supposed to print 89?

Comment: @Pimgd C89 and C90 is the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206568/what-is-the-difference-between-c-c99-ansi-c-and-gnu-c-a-general-confusion-reg/17209532#17209532

Comment: They mean the same thing but it's not the same string. Standing by my original question.

Comment: @Pimgd The purpose of the above code is not to sate some artificial task to print strings after a given format. The purpose is to demonstrate how real-word applications outside the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) prints which C version the program was compiled with. C90 is more correct to use than "C89" or "ANSI-C".