# How to check which version of C my compiler is using?

Tags: c

Is there any piece of code I can write or any other way to check which version of the C language my compiler is compiling?

I was wondering if there was a way for me to see if the compiler in question is C89, C99, C11, C18 etc. Perhaps utilizing `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: @pzaenger thanks for that, but I was wondering if there was a way for me to see if the compiler in question is C89, C99, C11, C18 etc. Perhaps utilizing `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify this within the question. It will be more helpful for future users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the `__STDC_VERSION__` macro, which hast the format YYYYMM and from that deduce whether you run C89, C99, C11 or C18.

See also [What is the __STDC_VERSION__ value for C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294207/what-is-the-stdc-version-value-for-c11)

Answer (score 5):

> How to check which version of C my compiler is using?

To check against standard versions, use `__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__`.  Various compilers also offer implementation specific macros for further refinement.

`__STDC__` available with C89 version and onward.

Compliant versions prior to C94 do not certainly define `__STDC_VERSION__`.  Since then it is a `long` constant.

The common values found include:

```
199409L
199901L
201112L
201710L
```

Putting that together

```
#if defined(__STDC__)
  #if defined(__STDC_VERSION__)
    printf("Version %ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
  #else
    puts("Standard C - certainly 1989");
  #endif
#else
  puts("Pre 1989 or non-compliant C");
#endif
```

Example [macro usage](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216119/29485)